# Flutter is showing Expected to find ','. in main.dart file

Tags: flutter, dart

[why Flutter is showing Expected to find ','. in main.dart file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDKS3.png)

Flutter is showing Expected to find ','. in main.dart file

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDKS3.png

Comment: add `,` to`Appbar closing` bracket

Comment: + consider including code-snippet instead of code-image

Comment: ohhhh god. thank you Ravindra S. Patil

Answer (score 0):

you need to add a comma after each line of code like this:

```dart
home: Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(...), //here a comma
  body: YoueBodyWidget(),
  
),
```

Comment: Can you please help me why my image not load from asset. if use network image it works. [link](https://ibb.co/KNQT8ZQ) [link](https://ibb.co/NZJMv9M)

Comment: ``i`` will be upper case on `AssestImage("I..."`  and pubspec.yaml. And rebuild the app. Hot restart wont work for this

Answer (score -1):

on which line you watching this error just add ',' in end

like:

home: Scaffold(
appBar: AppBar(...), //here a comma
body: YoueBodyWidget(),

),